# $ab$ conjugates with $a^{-1}b^{-1}$

Tags: group-theory

Given that a group $G$ has the property that every element conjugates with its inverse, I want to prove that $ab$ conjugates with $a^{-1}b^{-1}$.

I have tried but only seem to get out gibberish. I know that $\exists g,h \in G:$
$$
a=ga^{-1}g^{-1} \\
b=hb^{-1}h^{-1}
$$

It is easy enough to see that $ab$ conjugates with $b^{-1}a^{-1}$, but that is not what's asked. Any tips?

Comment: "Conjugates"? $\quad $

Comment: Can you tell me what is the inverse of $ab$ ? I just want to make sure you know the inverse of $ab$ correctly.

Comment: I might have translated it incorrectly, but I meant to say that for any $a \in G$ we can write $a = ha^{-1}h^{-1}$.

Comment: @JDijkstra No no, can you just tell me the inverse of $ab$

Comment: @Leth $b^{-1}a^{-1}$.

Comment: where is the exercise from?

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth It was written by a teacher for an old exam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are given that $ab$ is conjugate to $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1} a^{-1}$.

Also, $b^{-1} a^{-1}$ is conjugate to $a^{-1} b^{-1}$, because
$$b (b^{-1} a^{-1}) b^{-1} =  a^{-1} b^{-1}
$$
This one is a special case of a general fact: every word is conjugate to every cyclic permutation of that word.

And here is one more general fact: conjugation is transitive, meaning that if $x$ is conjugate to $y$ and $y$ is conjugate to $z$ then $x$ is conjugate to $z$, because
$$gxg^{-1} = y \quad\text{and}\quad hyh^{-1}=z \implies (hg)x(hg)^{-1}=z
$$

Therefore, $ab$ is conjugate to $a^{-1}b^{-1}$.

Comment: You need to edit this answer as you have somehow replaced given part by what is asked and visa versa.

Comment: Out of curiousity how did you come up with this solution? I've tried for hours but I didn't see you could just left multiply with $aa^{-1}$.

Comment: Oops, thanks @BhaskarVashishth.

Comment: I came up with this solution because I already know those two general facts in my answer, in particular I knew the proof of the cyclic conjugacy fact, and I instantly recognized that $a^{-1}b^{-1}$ is a cyclic permutation of $b^{-1}a^{-1}$.